# Not showing "My Mac" as run target in xcode 14.3 or higher

Tags: xcode, x86-64, arm64, xcode15

I have a Mac app project that I was able to run successfully on Xcode 14.2. but when I tried to run it on Xcode 14.3 and 15, I encountered an issue. These newer versions of Xcode do not display "My Mac" as a run target, even though the app is already configured with Standard Architectures.

I have upgraded my mac to Sonoma beta macOS so older version of xcode not working and I have to use xcode 15 and it should show "My Mac" as run target as per architecture but unfortunately not working.

[image]